# Localhost:5000 always hosting, Flask React

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have a really weird problem, I am working on a simple flask/react app, hosted normally on localhost:5000 by flask. Everything was working fine until I closed the terminal application and for some reason the server kept on running, now everytime i go to localhost:5000 the application seems to respond and shows me the react landing page, whether or not i am purposefully running the server. Is there some way to find the source of this or just to turn off all servers? I tried rebooting my laptop but the site seems to stay up, I havent changed any of my start up settings, i have no idea why it would turn on at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your browser is caching your React landing page, so the only possible solution I can think of is to clear your cache. There are numerous tutorials for this depending on your browser.

Comment: @Tzanker I think for hard reloads (on Chrome and Firefox at least) which apparently also clear the cache it is possible to also use: `Control + Shift + R`